# Dynamic 2D array losing second dimension

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamically allocated, 2D array that is being populated within a pair of for loops.  For some reason by the end of the for loops all of the elements are in inaccessible memory.

```
/*************Start Positive Phase*************************/
double *posHidActivations = new double[FEATURES];
memset(posHidActivations, 0, sizeof(double)*FEATURES);

double *posVisActivations = new double[m_NumRatings];
memset(posVisActivations, 0, sizeof(double)*m_NumRatings);


double **posProducts = new double*[FEATURES];
for(int i=0; i<FEATURES; i++)
   posProducts[i] = new double[m_NumRatings];
for(int i=0; i<FEATURES; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<m_NumRatings; j++)
      posProducts[i][j] = 0;
/* manually verified elements are valid and 
   initialized to 0 with gdb */

// for each hidden node
for(int j=0; j<FEATURES; j++)
{   
   // sum up inputs from the visible layer
   for(int i=0; i<m_NumRatings; i++)
   {   
      double input = m_VisLayer[i]*m_Weights[i][j];
      double prob = sigmoid(input, m_HidItemBias[j]);
      posProducts[j][i] = m_VisLayer[i]*prob;
      posVisActivations[j]+=m_VisLayer[i];   // commenting out this line fixes
      posHidActivations[j]+=prob;
   }   
   // posProducts[i][0] is valid here
}  
/* posProducts[0][0] is a segfault 
   using gdp verified that posProducts is a valid double**
   and posProducts[0] is a valid double*
```

Declarations for identifiers not in the previous snippit:

```
int m_NumRatings;

m_VisLayer = new double[m_NumRatings];

m_Weights = new double* [m_NumRatings];
for(int i=0; i<m_NumRatings; i++)
   m_Weights[i] = new double [FEATURES];

m_HidItemBias = new double[FEATURES];
```

'FEATURES' is a #defined constant

Edit:  I forgot to mention.  Later in the program is a logically identical code block using different identifiers (posProducts -> negProducts, m_VisLayer -> m_HidLayer, etc).  That block does not show any of the same symptoms.  I can't find any logical difference no matter how many times I compare the code.

Comment: Have you considered replacing `double**` with `vector<vector<double> >`?

Comment: Does posProducts and posProducts[0] point to the same place when it segfaults as when it does not (e.g. when you verify right after allocating memory)?

Comment: The thought has occurred to me.  The reason I haven't yet is because there is enough code in the program already that going back and replacing the arrays with vectors would be very time consuming.  If i can't figure out this bug soon I'll be doing it regardless i guess.

Comment: Not related to your problem as far as I can tell, but I really find it confusing that you first have `i` as the outer iteration variable and `j` as the inner iteration variable, and later on, their roles are reversed. It generally helps readability if you keep things consistent.

Comment: @n0rd  yes it does.  Both levels of pointers point to the same exact addresses.  Its the final, 1D arrays that seem to disappear.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the `memset` at the top of the code if you replace `new double[FEATURES]` with `new double[FEATURES]()`. Note the trailing pair of empty parenthesis.

Comment: @Fred.  I hear you on the weird indexing.  The reason i did it that way is the math formulas the code is based off of use i subscripts for visible items and j subscripts for hidden items.  Doing the same in my program helps me when comparing the code to the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note:

```
posVisActivations[j]+=m_VisLayer[i];   // commenting out this line fixes
```

The index for posVisActivations is j, which ranges from 0 to m_FEATURES, but posVisActivations is declared to be an array with m_numRatings elements.

So, you are writing past the end of the array. You probably meant to use `i` as the index:

```
posVisActivations[i]+=m_VisLayer[i];   // commenting out this line fixes
```

HTH.

Comment: Sometimes it amazes me how I can stare at a piece of code so long and miss something so obvious.  Plus part of the reason for my weird indexing is that anything that is 'Vis' should be indexed with 'i' and anything 'Hid' with 'j'.  Yet I still miss it!